# how to open the one page to the in new browser windows in asp.net coding

Tags: javascript, html

how to open the one page to the in new browser windows in coding?

Comment: I don't know asp.net, but I'm sure you'll need JavaScript for that. Or the deprecated `_blank` target attribute.

Comment: target isn't deprecated ( http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html — see, no 'D' )

Comment: I don't get why this question was downvoted so much.  He is here to learn =/ He should have simply been corrected.  By the way, look into window.open(url, "_blank");

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with the help of javascript function `window.open`

```
  window.open ("http://www.example.com","yourwindow");
```

Comment: Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>detailedresults=window.open('Machineinfo.aspx?MachineID=" + MachineID + "',_ blank');</script>");
I tride above but not  working

Comment: you are missing single colon before _blank. This will work.
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>detailedresults=window.open('Machineinfo.aspx?MachineID=" + 1 + "','_blank');</script>");